# Pyinstaller not working for package pyreadstat

Tags: python, pandas, pyinstaller

I'm trying to use `pyinstaller` with a simple python program. Creating the windows .exe completes successfully but when I run the .exe program, I get the error

```
.\dist\myapp\myapp.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pac_cleaner\myapp.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pyreadstat as pr
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module
  File "pyreadstat\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
  File "pyreadstat\pyreadstat.pyx", line 1, in init pyreadstat.pyreadstat
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyreadstat._readstat_writer'
[11460] Failed to execute script 'myapp' due to unhandled exception!
```

The program itself is

```
import pyreadstat as pr
import pandas as pd

def hello():
    print("Hello")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    hello()
```

and I use `pyinstaller` as so

```
pyinstaller .\pac_cleaner\myapp.py  --noconfirm --hidden-import=pandas --hidden-import=pyreadstat
```

any ideas?

Comment: You have to explicitly add the pyreadstat package .pyd files, probably one by one (there are three of them _readstat_parser.pyd, _readstat_writer.pyd, pyreadstat.pyd)

Answer (score 0):

Using the `--collect-submodules` works. I'm posting the answer from the [official repo discussion](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/discussions/6408)

```
pyinstaller  .\pac_cleaner\myapp.py  --noconfirm --collect-submodules pyreadstat
```